# How can I wire a crane stock battery to a PEQ box?

Tags: equipment, airsoft

A while ago, I got a crane stock battery for the G&G GR15. Of course, as things happen, I ended up getting a different gun (the ICS CXP-UK1).

Since the CXP is wired to the front, is there a PEQ box large enough to house a crane stock battery? Or would it be more sensible to either buy a smaller battery (to fit in the RIS), or a crane stock (and wire the gun to the rear)?

Answer (score 1):

100% buy a smaller battery, to rewrite the gun you will have to take apart the entire gun, including the gearbox and reorganize it, not to mention some guns don't have the proper holes to rout the wires to a crane stock. You can get pretty powerful batteries that are fairly small, surely small enough for it to fit in the rails.